# matlab - converting double -8.451147490804935e+03 TO -8.451

Tags: matlab, double, number-formatting

Any tryouts I've made converted it to 8451.114+.... while normal doubles ( without the e and only 4 digits precision ) were their original value.

tried str2num double converts , sprintf
and all of googles first pages ideas :O

and because of that value my whole matrix is ruined because it converts anything in it to this
precision and changes the values.

thanks

Comment: Provide a simple example that reproduces the issue, and rewrite the body of your question: it's barely comprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You type:

```
format longG
```

in the prompt

Comment: same issue. number is changed to *1000 for some reason

Comment: I thought you were having a formatting issue. Matlab is not wrong. Try to see why the computation is giving you the value multiplied by 1000.

Comment: numbers have changed before i guess... 2 am is enough :) thanks for your help ill continue tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, you could also do this way:

```
format shortG
str2num('-8.451147490804935E+03')
```